# mvn clean install causes ArchiverException

Tags: java, maven

I did an `mvn clean install` and it gives me an "`ArchiverException`" with the following error messages and build failure.

```
[INFO] Unpacking /home/dev237/.m2/repository/org/neo4j/spatial/osm-test- data/20100819/osm-test-data-20100819.jar to


/home/dev237/Projects/spatial/target
   with includes null and excludes:null
org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.ArchiverException: Error while expanding /home/dev237/.m2/repository/org/neo4j/spatial/osm-test-data/20100819/osm-test-data-20100819.jar
    at   org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.zip.AbstractZipUnArchiver.execute(AbstractZipUnArchiver.java:132)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.AbstractUnArchiver.extract(AbstractUnArchiver.java:108)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.dependency.AbstractDependencyMojo.unpack(AbstractDependencyMojo.java:260)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.dependency.UnpackDependenciesMojo.execute(UnpackDependenciesMojo.java:90)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:622)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Negative seek offset
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.seek(Native Method)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.zip.ZipFile.positionAtCentralDirectory(ZipFile.java:383)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.zip.ZipFile.populateFromCentralDirectory(ZipFile.java:254)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:148)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.zip.AbstractZipUnArchiver.execute(AbstractZipUnArchiver.java:113)
    ... 24 more
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Total time: 4:36.563s
    [INFO] Finished at: Tue Jun 17 09:49:47 IST 2014
    [INFO] Final Memory: 7M/61M
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-     plugin:2.1:unpack-dependencies (get-test-data) on project neo4j-spatial: Error unpacking file: /home/dev237/.m2/repository/org/neo4j/spatial/osm-test-data/20100819/osm-test-data-20100819.jar to: /home/dev237/Projects/spatial/target
[ERROR] org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.ArchiverException: Error while expanding /home/dev237/.m2/repository/org/neo4j/spatial/osm-test-data/20100819/osm-test-data-20100819.jar: Negative seek offset
     [ERROR] -> [Help 1]
```

mvn clean install -X results

```
[DEBUG]   Included: org.apache.maven.doxia:doxia-decoration-model:jar:1.0-alpha-7
[DEBUG]   Excluded: org.apache.maven:maven-artifact:jar:2.0.9
[DEBUG]   Excluded: org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:2.0.9
[DEBUG]   Excluded: org.apache.maven:maven-project:jar:2.0.9
[DEBUG]   Excluded: org.apache.maven:maven-settings:jar:2.0.9
[DEBUG]   Excluded: org.apache.maven:maven-profile:jar:2.0.9
[DEBUG]   Excluded: org.apache.maven:maven-artifact-manager:jar:2.0.9
[DEBUG]   Excluded: org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-registry:jar:2.0.9
[DEBUG]   Excluded: org.apache.maven:maven-model:jar:2.0.9
[DEBUG]   Excluded: org.apache.maven:maven-core:jar:2.0.9
[DEBUG]   Excluded: org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-parameter-documenter:jar:2.0.9
[DEBUG]   Excluded: org.apache.maven:maven-repository-metadata:jar:2.0.9
[DEBUG]   Excluded: org.apache.maven:maven-error-diagnostics:jar:2.0.9
[DEBUG]   Excluded: org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-descriptor:jar:2.0.9
[DEBUG]   Excluded: org.apache.maven:maven-monitor:jar:2.0.9
[DEBUG]   Excluded: classworlds:classworlds:jar:1.1
[DEBUG]   Excluded: org.apache.maven.wagon:wagon-provider-api:jar:1.0-alpha-6
[DEBUG]   Excluded: org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-container-default:jar:1.0-alpha-9-stable-1
[DEBUG] Configuring mojo org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.1:unpack-dependencies from plugin realm ClassRealm[plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.1, parent: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@3225753d]
[DEBUG] Configuring mojo 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.1:unpack-dependencies' with basic configurator -->
[DEBUG]   (s) copyPom = false
[DEBUG]   (f) excludeTransitive = false
[DEBUG]   (s) failOnMissingClassifierArtifact = true
[DEBUG]   (f) includeGroupIds = org.neo4j.spatial
[DEBUG]   (s) local =        id: local
      url: file:///home/dev237/.m2/repository
   layout: none

[DEBUG]   (s) markersDirectory = /home/dev237/Projects /spatial/target/dependency-maven-plugin-markers
[DEBUG]   (f) outputAbsoluteArtifactFilename = false
[DEBUG]   (s) outputDirectory = /home/dev237/Projects/spatial/target
[DEBUG]   (f) overWriteIfNewer = true
[DEBUG]   (f) overWriteReleases = false
[DEBUG]   (f) overWriteSnapshots = false
[DEBUG]   (f) project = MavenProject: org.neo4j:neo4j-spatial:0.13-neo4j-2.1.1 @ /home/dev237/Projects/spatial/pom.xml
[DEBUG]   (f) reactorProjects = [MavenProject: org.neo4j:neo4j-spatial:0.13-neo4j-2.1.1 @ /home/dev237/Projects/spatial/pom.xml]
[DEBUG]   (s) remoteRepos = [       id: osgeo
     [INFO] Unpacking /home/dev237/.m2/repository/org/neo4j/spatial/osm-test-  data/20100819/osm-test-data-20100819.jar to
 /home/dev237/Projects/spatial/target
  with includes null and excludes:null
  [DEBUG] Expanding: /home/dev237/.m2/repository/org/neo4j/spatial/osm-test-  data/20100819/osm-test-data-20100819.jar into /home/dev237/Projects /spatial/target
```

org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.ArchiverException: Error while expanding /home/dev237/.m2/repository/org/neo4j/spatial/osm-test-data/20100819/osm-test-data-20100819.jar
    at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.zip.AbstractZipUnArchiver.execute(AbstractZipUnArchiver.java:132)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.AbstractUnArchiver.extract(AbstractUnArchiver.java:108)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.dependency.AbstractDependencyMojo.unpack(AbstractDependencyMojo.java:260)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.dependency.UnpackDependenciesMojo.execute(UnpackDependenciesMojo.java:90)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:622)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Negative seek offset
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.seek(Native Method)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.zip.ZipFile.positionAtCentralDirectory(ZipFile.java:383)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.zip.ZipFile.populateFromCentralDirectory(ZipFile.java:254)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.zip.ZipFile.(ZipFile.java:148)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.zip.AbstractZipUnArchiver.execute(AbstractZipUnArchiver.java:113)
    ... 24 more
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Total time: 4:39.108s
    [INFO] Finished at: Tue Jun 17 11:06:59 IST 2014
    [INFO] Final Memory: 7M/48M
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.1:unpack-dependencies (get-test-data) on project neo4j-spatial: Error unpacking file: /home/dev237/.m2/repository/org/neo4j/spatial/osm-test-data/20100819/osm-test-data-20100819.jar to: /home/dev237/Projects/ /spatial/target
[ERROR] org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.ArchiverException: Error while expanding /home/dev237/.m2/repository/org/neo4j/spatial/osm-test-data/20100819/osm-test-data-20100819.jar: Negative seek offset

Comment: Mostly looks like a corrupted jar in your local repository. Delete artifacts in there and give it a try again?

Comment: did you mean .m2/repository folder?I am new to this.If it is blunder question.I am sorry..

Comment: yes, plainly rm -rf the .m2/repository/org/neo4j/spatial/osm-test-data/20100819 folder

Comment: thanku kilokahn.I tried your suggestion .but getting same error with some other warnings like The POM for org.neo4j:server-api:jar:2.1.1 is invalid

Comment: Can you retry the mvn invocation with -X switch and post the entire error message as an edit?

Comment: Can you check if you have enough disk space? From the POM for org.neo4j:server-api:jar:2.1.1 is invalid it looks like it tried to download the POM in .m2/repository/org/neo4j/server-api/2.1.1/server-api-2.1.1.pom but didn't find enough place and hence it is deeming it as corrupted. Delete the .m2/repository/org/neo4j/server-api/2.1.1/ folder as well.

Comment: Ya yes.I will do.Please wait..

Comment: I have posted the result of mvn clean install -X wth editing.But it does not contain all output.Please help..

Comment: disk space? Can you run df -h /home/dev237/

Answer (score 0):

right click on the project

click on maven

than click on update dependencies

```
1)  Maven >Update Dependencies
```

and than after right click on project first

```
2)  Run As > Maven Clean
```

and after maven clean do maven install

```
3)  Run As > Maven Install
```

at last clean and bulid your project.

hope it will help you

Comment: I am new to this.Can you please specific.right clicking on project did not give any options like maven

Answer (score 0):

In your case, remove 'codehaus' directory  in .m2/org/ and then update maven project.

Comment: Hi anassesh. Thanks for the answer. To improve your answer further you should add some explanation what the error is, how it occurs and how your fix works so everyone can understand.