# getting NoClassDefFoundError ArchiverException when running mvn package

Tags: java, maven, heroku, maven-dependency-plugin

I want to deploy my tomcat based web application onto heroku host. So I followed the approach given in this link: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/java-webapp-runner. So here is my pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.heroku.sms-service</groupId>
    <artifactId>sms-service</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>sms-service Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.heroku</groupId>
            <artifactId>real-state-interface</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.jsimone</groupId>
            <artifactId>webapp-runner</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.30.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>sms-service</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals><goal>copy</goal></goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>com.github.jsimone</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>webapp-runner</artifactId>
                                    <version>8.0.30.2</version>
                                    <destFileName>webapp-runner.jar</destFileName>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

The problem is that when I run "mvn package" I get an Error:

[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.3:copy (default) @ sms-service ---
[WARNING] Error injecting: org.apache.maven.plugin.dependency.fromConfiguration.CopyMojo
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/plexus/archiver/ArchiverException

and this:

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.3:copy (default) on project sms-service: Execution default of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.3:copy failed: A required class was missing while executing org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.3:copy: org/codehaus/plexus/archiver/ArchiverException

Here is some of the output I get from running "mvn package -X":

```
[DEBUG] adding entry WEB-INF/lib/maven-dependency-plugin-2.3.jar
[DEBUG] adding entry WEB-INF/lib/tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar
[DEBUG] adding entry WEB-INF/lib/annotations-1.3.9.jar
[DEBUG] adding entry WEB-INF/lib/tomcat-el-api-8.0.30.jar
[DEBUG] adding entry WEB-INF/lib/stax-api-1.0.1.jar
[DEBUG] adding entry WEB-INF/lib/javax.servlet-api-3.0.1.jar
[DEBUG] adding entry WEB-INF/lib/netty-3.5.5.Final.jar
[DEBUG] adding entry WEB-INF/lib/real-state-interface-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
[DEBUG] adding entry WEB-INF/lib/jcommander-1.27.jar
[DEBUG] adding entry WEB-INF/lib/tomcat-juli-8.0.30.jar
[DEBUG] adding entry WEB-INF/lib/httpcore-4.3.jar
[DEBUG] adding entry WEB-INF/lib/commons-io-2.3.jar
[DEBUG] adding entry WEB-INF/lib/tomcat-servlet-api-8.0.30.jar
[DEBUG] adding entry WEB-INF/web.xml
[DEBUG] adding entry WEB-INF/classes/com/heroku/realstate/sms_service/SmsSender.class
[DEBUG] adding entry WEB-INF/classes/com/heroku/realstate/sms_service/ConfirmationChecker.class
[DEBUG] adding entry index.jsp
[INFO] WEB-INF/web.xml already added, skipping
[DEBUG] adding directory META-INF/maven/
[DEBUG] adding directory META-INF/maven/com.heroku.sms-service/
[DEBUG] adding directory META-INF/maven/com.heroku.sms-service/sms-service/
[DEBUG] adding entry META-INF/maven/com.heroku.sms-service/sms-service/pom.xml
[DEBUG] adding entry META-INF/maven/com.heroku.sms-service/sms-service/pom.properties
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.3:copy (default) @ sms-service ---
[DEBUG] Dependency collection stats: {ConflictMarker.analyzeTime=0, ConflictMarker.markTime=0, ConflictMarker.nodeCount=1, ConflictIdSorter.graphTime=0, ConflictIdSorter.topsortTime=0, ConflictIdSorter.conflictIdCount=1, ConflictIdSorter.conflictIdCycleCount=0, ConflictResolver.totalTime=0, ConflictResolver.conflictItemCount=1, DefaultDependencyCollector.collectTime=7, DefaultDependencyCollector.transformTime=1}
[DEBUG] org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:jar:2.3:
[DEBUG]    org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:1.1:runtime
[DEBUG] Created new class realm plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.3
[DEBUG] Importing foreign packages into class realm plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.3
[DEBUG]   Imported:  < maven.api
[DEBUG] Populating class realm plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.3
[DEBUG]   Included: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:jar:2.3
[DEBUG]   Included: org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:1.1
[DEBUG] Configuring mojo org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.3:copy from plugin realm ClassRealm[plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.3, parent: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@5c647e05]
[WARNING] Error injecting: org.apache.maven.plugin.dependency.fromConfiguration.CopyMojo
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/plexus/archiver/ArchiverException
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2671)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2020)
    at com.google.inject.spi.InjectionPoint.forConstructorOf(InjectionPoint.java:245)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl.create(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:99)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createUninitializedBinding(InjectorImpl.java:658)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createJustInTimeBinding(InjectorImpl.java:882)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createJustInTimeBindingRecursive(InjectorImpl.java:805)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getJustInTimeBinding(InjectorImpl.java:282)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getBindingOrThrow(InjectorImpl.java:214)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProviderOrThrow(InjectorImpl.java:1006)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProvider(InjectorImpl.java:1038)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProvider(InjectorImpl.java:1001)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance(InjectorImpl.java:1051)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.space.AbstractDeferredClass.get(AbstractDeferredClass.java:48)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision(ProviderInternalFactory.java:81)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.provision(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:53)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory$1.call(ProviderInternalFactory.java:65)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:115)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.bean.BeanScheduler$Activator.onProvision(BeanScheduler.java:176)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:126)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:68)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.circularGet(ProviderInternalFactory.java:63)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:45)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:1016)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1092)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2.get(InjectorImpl.java:1012)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.Guice4$1.get(Guice4.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.LazyBeanEntry.getValue(LazyBeanEntry.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.LazyPlexusBean.getValue(LazyPlexusBean.java:51)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:263)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:255)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getConfiguredMojo(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:517)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:121)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.ArchiverException
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:50)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.unsynchronizedLoadClass(ClassRealm.java:271)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:247)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:239)
    ... 55 more
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3.831 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-03-13T07:53:48+03:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 12M/110M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.3:copy (default) on project sms-service: Execution default of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.3:copy failed: A required class was missing while executing org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.3:copy: org/codehaus/plexus/archiver/ArchiverException
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] realm =    plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.3
[ERROR] strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
[ERROR] urls[0] = file:/home/hossein/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/2.3/maven-dependency-plugin-2.3.jar
[ERROR] urls[1] = file:/home/hossein/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/1.1/plexus-utils-1.1.jar
[ERROR] Number of foreign imports: 1
[ERROR] import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------: org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.ArchiverException
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.3:copy (default) on project sms-service: Execution default of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.3:copy failed: A required class was missing while executing org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.3:copy: org/codehaus/plexus/archiver/ArchiverException
-----------------------------------------------------
realm =    plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.3
strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
urls[0] = file:/home/hossein/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/2.3/maven-dependency-plugin-2.3.jar
urls[1] = file:/home/hossein/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/1.1/plexus-utils-1.1.jar
Number of foreign imports: 1
import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]

-----------------------------------------------------

    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution default of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.3:copy failed: A required class was missing while executing org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.3:copy: org/codehaus/plexus/archiver/ArchiverException
-----------------------------------------------------
realm =    plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.3
strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
urls[0] = file:/home/hossein/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/2.3/maven-dependency-plugin-2.3.jar
urls[1] = file:/home/hossein/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/1.1/plexus-utils-1.1.jar
Number of foreign imports: 1
import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]

-----------------------------------------------------

    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:168)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginContainerException: A required class was missing while executing org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.3:copy: org/codehaus/plexus/archiver/ArchiverException
-----------------------------------------------------
realm =    plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.3
strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
urls[0] = file:/home/hossein/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/2.3/maven-dependency-plugin-2.3.jar
urls[1] = file:/home/hossein/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/1.1/plexus-utils-1.1.jar
Number of foreign imports: 1
import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]

-----------------------------------------------------

    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:166)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/plexus/archiver/ArchiverException
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2671)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2020)
    at com.google.inject.spi.InjectionPoint.forConstructorOf(InjectionPoint.java:245)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl.create(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:99)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createUninitializedBinding(InjectorImpl.java:658)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createJustInTimeBinding(InjectorImpl.java:882)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createJustInTimeBindingRecursive(InjectorImpl.java:805)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getJustInTimeBinding(InjectorImpl.java:282)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getBindingOrThrow(InjectorImpl.java:214)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProviderOrThrow(InjectorImpl.java:1006)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProvider(InjectorImpl.java:1038)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProvider(InjectorImpl.java:1001)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance(InjectorImpl.java:1051)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.space.AbstractDeferredClass.get(AbstractDeferredClass.java:48)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision(ProviderInternalFactory.java:81)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.provision(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:53)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory$1.call(ProviderInternalFactory.java:65)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:115)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.bean.BeanScheduler$Activator.onProvision(BeanScheduler.java:176)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:126)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:68)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.circularGet(ProviderInternalFactory.java:63)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:45)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:1016)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1092)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2.get(InjectorImpl.java:1012)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.Guice4$1.get(Guice4.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.LazyBeanEntry.getValue(LazyBeanEntry.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.LazyPlexusBean.getValue(LazyPlexusBean.java:51)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:263)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:255)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getConfiguredMojo(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:517)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:121)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.ArchiverException
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:50)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.unsynchronizedLoadClass(ClassRealm.java:271)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:247)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:239)
    ... 55 more
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginContainerException
```

What is wrong? Actually I'm not expert in maven but I think there's something strange. Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: Please put the result of mvn package -x here, that might help us understand that error better.

Comment: I've added part of it. I hope it helps! And thank you in advance @MukundGandlur

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need `webapp-runner` as a dependency -- only copied into the `target/` directory in the `package` phase. Try removing it from your `<dependencies>` element or marking it as `provided`.

Also, try upgrading `maven-dependency-plugin` to 2.10 or something more recent.

Here is a [sample app](https://github.com/kissaten/webapp-runner-minimal) that does what you are trying to do.

Comment: I removed webapp-runner from dependencies and used maven-dependency-plugin 2.10 but it didn't work. It still gives me that error

Comment: What is the output when you run `mvn -version`?

Comment: latest maven -> Apache Maven 3.3.9 (bb52d8502b132ec0a5a3f4c09453c07478323dc5; 2015-11-10T20:11:47+03:30)
Maven home: /opt/apache-maven-3.3.9
Java version: 1.8.0_74, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_74/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "4.2.0-27-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"

Comment: Have you run `mvn clean` recently? Looks like there might be an old maven-dependency-plugin bug you've run into http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24255828/mvn-clean-install-causes-archiverexception and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24255828/mvn-clean-install-causes-archiverexception

Comment: No. It has nothing to do with that because I can run mvn clean without problem in other projects.

Answer (score 0):

I have also got the same error.
After removing the below folders from maven ,

```
1.\.m2\repository\org\apache\maven
2.\.m2\repository\org\codehaus
```

Try :
mvn clean package

maven downloads the dependency freshly and worked fine.